# Removing color and horizontal rules on first column

Tags: tables, formatting

I have made the following table as the tex describes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,total={170mm,257mm},left=20mm,top=20mm}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{libertine}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Table Settings
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}%To keep spacing of text in tables
\usepackage{colortbl,xcolor}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Color


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
         \centering
         \def\arraystretch{1.5}
         \label{TOR:FREEDOM:COMPARE}
        \begin{tabular}{c|L{7cm}|L{7cm}|}
            \hline
              \rowcolor{red} \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textcolor{white}{\large{\textbf{TOR}}}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textcolor{white}{\large{\textbf{Freedom}}}}\\
             \hline
             %-----Category---|-------- TOR ----- | ----- Freedom ------- 
              \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Privacy}}& + Anonymization& + Pseudo-anonymization\\ 
              & + Unlinkability & \\
             \hline
             \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Operational}}&+ Hidden Services & + Mailing System \\
              &+ Decentralized System & - Partially Centralized\\
              &+ Use AES & - Use 3DES\\
              &+ Open Protocol & - Closed Product\\
              &- TCP Only & + TCP and UDP Support\\
             \hline
             \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Ux}}& + Easily Installable Local Socks Proxy & - Kernel Module\\
             & + Apps already supporing TOR build-in (TOR Browser)&\\
             & - Use as low latency as possible but practically latency still noticable. (on personal use)&\\
             & - May cause some law problems to exit node owners because of also used for illegal activities.\cite{TOR:LEGAL:RUSSIA} &\\
             \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Comparison Table between Freedom and TOR}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

And the table is displayed as:
[image: Table Currently displayed]

But I want to display it as:

[image: Table how I want to get displayed]

May I have some help on how to do that?

Comment: Yes, you may :o) What do you mean with ‘formatting of the  1st column’?

Comment: I mean a column without rules and colors, as the image shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? I took the liberty to remove the vertical rule in the first row, as I think it looks nicer, and it simplifies the code, and the various hyphens in the lists with endashes. A simple solution to visualize the horizontal rules conists in using `\hhline` (`\clines aren't visible):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=20mm}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{libertine}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Table Settings
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}%To keep spacing of text in tables
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Color

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
         \centering
         \def\arraystretch{1.5}
         \label{TOR:FREEDOM:COMPARE}
        \begin{tabular}{c|L{7cm}|L{7cm}|}
            \hhline{~|--}
              \rowcolor{red}[\dimexpr\tabcolsep + 0.4pt][\tabcolsep]\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{\cellcolor{white}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{white}\large\bfseries TOR} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{white}\large\bfseries Freedom}\\
            \hhline{~|--}
             %-----Category---|-------- TOR ----- | ----- Freedom -------
              \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Privacy}}& + Anonymization& + Pseudo-anonymization\\
              & + Unlinkability & \\
            \hhline{~--}
             \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Operational}}& idden Services & + Mailing System \\
              &+ Decentralized System & – Partially Centralized\\
              &+ Use AES & – Use 3DES\\
              &+ Open Protocol & – Closed Product\\
              & – TCP Only & + TCP and UDP Support\\
            \hhline{~|--}
             \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Ux}}& + Easily Installable Local Socks Proxy & – Kernel Module\\
             & + Apps already supporing TOR build-in (TOR Browser)&\\
             & – Use as low latency as possible but practically latency still noticable. (on personal use)&\\
             & – May cause some law problems to exit node owners because of also used for illegal activities.\cite{TOR:LEGAL:RUSSIA} &\\
            \hhline{~|--}
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Comparison Table between Freedom and TOR}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]